# How to build ONLY applications in android system build

Tags: android, android-build

I am building Android source code for SDK. But whenever I change something in my application, I have to build complete source again which takes a considerable amount of time.

Now what I want to know, is there any way to build only app folder so that only applications available in my source would be built?

I cannot build my app in Eclipse due to some limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you generate jars then use them as libraries in your application, as opposed to compiling the whole source code?

Comment: I have tried this many times. It does not work when I compile with Eclipse. This used to be worked till 2.3 but I don't know why its not working in JB. If I install my linux build compiled apk, it works fine but when I compile same app with Eclipse, it gives NoClassDefFoundError.
Means Eclipse compiled apk is a generic certificate apk and linux build compiled apk is genrated is system/app apk means different certificate(I am thinking like this) so it does not give any error.

Comment: Oh I see. New eclipse ADT has changed the way dependency is computed. Create a new project, or just do Android->Fix on the project